# Querying a record with a many-to-many relationship based on whether or not it has certain corresponding records

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

This app runs on Rails 4 and Ruby 2.

I have two models, Key and Chord, that have a many-to-many relationship `through: Keychords`.

Keychord has two fields: `key_id` and `chord_id`

I would like to run a query that returns all Keys that have every chord in a given array of chords.

E.g.

key1 is related to chords with the IDs: `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

key2 is related to chords with the IDs: `[1, 3, 4, 6]`

key3 is related to chords with the IDs: `[2, 3, 5, 6]`

key4 is related to chords with the IDs: `[1, 3, 4, 5]`

If I have an array of Chord IDs: `[2, 3]`

I want the query to return `[key1, key3]`

---

*Psuedo-code that I am going for but don't know how to actually write:*

```
Key.with(:chords, [2,3])
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
class Key < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :with_chords, ->(chords) { joins(:keychords).where(keychords: {chord_id: chords}).group("#{table_name}.#{primary_key}").having('COUNT(DISTINCT keychords.chord) = ?', chords.size)
end

Key.with_chords([2,3])
```

UPDATE - EXPLANATION:

This is in fact pretty hacky, but so far I have not seen better solution.
Example, let's say we have table:

```
#Table A   |   #Table B
  id       |     id         a_id     key_id
---------------------------------------------------   
  1        |     1            1        2
  2        |     2            3        3
  3        |     3            3        2
  4        |     4            4        1
  5        |     5            2        3
           |     6            4        2
```

And we are looking for elements from A associated with key_ids 2 and 3.

First step is to perform join with associated table. As a result of join, query will return n rows for a record with n associated rows in second table. It will Look like this:

```
 a.id     b.id    b.a_id    b.key_id
--------------------------------------
  1        1        1          2
  2        5        2          3   
  3        2        3          3
  3        3        3          2
  4        4        4          1
  4        6        4          2
```

Note that `A` records without associations are not returned at all.
Next step is to filter those rows and take only those with associations we are looking for (2 OR 3) This is done by `where` method. Result:

```
 a.id     b.id    b.a_id    b.key_id
--------------------------------------
  1        1        1          2
  2        5        2          3   
  3        2        3          3
  3        3        3          2
  4        6        4          2
```

Next step is to group it by `a.id`. Together with grouping we will add having statement, which will count all different values of `b.key_id` and reject those groups which have them less than initial list of ids. This ensures us that returned records have all the supplied keys.

```
  a.id | COUNT(DISTINCT b.key_id)
-----------------
  1    |    1    
  2    |    1  
  3    |    2      # The only result
  4    |    1
```

Comment: Thanks, testing this now. Just to clarify, should I be leaving it as "#{table_name}.#{primary_key}" or are `table_name` and `primary_key` placeholders? Also, I think you are missing a closing }. Should this be at the very end of the line?

Comment: Any chance you'd be willing to give a quick explanation of how each piece of the above query actually works?

Comment: Wow, thanks for taking the time to explain this. Much appreciated!

Comment: I know it's been a long time since you answered this, but I was hoping you'd be able to answer a followup question I have. How would you modify the above query to return only keys that have exactly chords [2, 3] instead of having chords [2, 3] amongst other chords? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @jackerman09 - The above statement should do that already. `having` statement will reject results having more than 2 matches.