# How can I update a Rails/SQL scope to return an exact match instead of a "contains" match?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my data model `Chord has_many :notes, through: :chordnotes`

The following scope in `Chord.rb` returns any `Chord` that has the `Notes` passed to the scope as an array of `Note` ids (e.g. `[9, 0, 5]`) per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120927/querying-a-record-with-a-many-to-many-relationship-based-on-whether-or-not-it-ha):

```
scope :with_notes, ->(notes) { joins(:chordnotes).where(chordnotes: {note_id: notes}).group("#{table_name}.#{primary_key}").having('COUNT(DISTINCT chordnotes.note_id) = ?', notes.size) }
```

How can I modify this scope to return only Chords that have *exactly* the notes passed in `notes` instead of any Chords that have, amongst others, the `notes` passed in?

For example:

If a D Chord has the notes with ids [9, 0, 5, 7], and the notes [9, 0, 5] were passed to the scope it would return the D Chord.

I want a new scope that would not return the D Chord because the `notes` passed in did not include [7] and therefore did not match the D Chord's notes exactly.

Thanks!

Comment: I guess this needs to be a `UNION`, but I'm not sure what the current "best" way to do this in rails is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit after understanding the need better:

I think the scope you have is good and gets you far enough. From this point you know that the result you'll get has all chords you need and a few extras. 
So what I would do, instead of moving too much logic to the DB is from that point add some rails logic on top using a class method. Yes it's a bit heavier as it will add 2 extra select calls. 
but... easier to maintain, it uses columns that should be under indexes and it's also easy to add cache on top of this method in the future in case you start getting real traffic.

The new method should look like this:

```
def self.with_exact_notes(notes)
  return if notes.empty?
  potential_ids = with_notes(notes).map(&:id)
  chords = Chord.includes(:chordnotes, :notes).where(id: potential_ids)
  chords.map {|ch| ch if ch.notes.map(&:id).sort == notes.sort }.compact
end
```

The method will first use your scope to get all the potential chords, then it will filter out the ones that don't have the exact notes ids that were passed into the method.

Then your query will be:

```
Chord.with_exact_notes(your_notes)
```

Comment: Hey, I don't think this is working. I need it to return an array of chords (whichever chords have the notes provided), so I don't have a `chord` record to call `.notes` on. This is why I had the scope on Chord in the first place. Does that make sense or am I misunderstanding your suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: ok so I didn't understand what you were trying to do. Which is find the chords that have these exact note ids. And I didn't see that your scope was longer than it was. I'll think about it and edit my answer

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I had to make one minor change, which was to add `.sort` on the results of the `.map` and on `notes` so that they arrays were considered to be equal even if the contents were in a different order.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using postgres, you can do this in the db using the `ARRAY_AGG` function:

```
  def self.with_notes(note_ids)
    return none if note_ids.blank?
    typecast_ids = note_ids.sort.map { |id| "#{id}::bigint" }.join(",")
    joins(:chordnotes).group(:id)
      .having("ARRAY_AGG(note_id ORDER BY note_id) = ARRAY[#{typecast_ids}]")
      .distinct
  end
```

The annoying part is that if your `id` column is a `bigint` you'll need to explicitly typecast the ids you're checking against (`map { |id| "#{id}::bigint" }`.

Be sure to sort both arrays when checking for equality (`note_ids.sort`, `ARRAY_AGG(note_id ORDER BY note_id)`).

Here's how this function will look as SQL:

```
pry(main)> Chord.with_notes([3,4]).first
  Chord Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  DISTINCT "chords".* FROM "chords" INNER JOIN "chordnotes" ON "chordnotes"."chord_id" = "chords"."id" GROUP BY "chords"."id" HAVING (ARRAY_AGG(note_id ORDER BY note_id) = ARRAY[3::bigint,4::bigint]) ORDER BY "chords"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
```

If you're using MySQL, you could use `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
  def self.with_notes(note_ids)
    joins(:chordnotes).group(:id)
      .having("GROUP_CONCAT(note_id ORDER BY note_id) = ?", note_ids.sort.join(","))
  end
```